# I want my container div to expand vertically to accommodate its content...?

Tags: html, containers, expand

I am creating a page that has a background image and the content is within a centered container that runs vertically down the page. Similar to the Yahoo! Answers layout: http://uk.answers.yahoo.com/

If you minimise your browser while on Yahoo! Answers the vertical scrolling just becomes 'longer' and the content all stays on the white container.

However, on mine when I minimise my browser the content towards the bottom of the container overflows and appears on the background image instead. I want the container to expand..

I do not want to use the overflow:auto or any other overflow attributes and I don't like the scroll bars.

Please see below and thank you in advance:

```
body {
background-image: url('images/ppback.jpg');
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
width:100%;
height:100%;
}

#container {
position: relative;
background: #440077;
width: 770px;
margin:0 auto;
top: 0px;
height: 100%; 
opacity: .7;
filter:alpha(opacity=70);
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the value height: 100% from #container. This is setting the max height of your container to the same height as the browser window, preventing anything longer than the window from being displayed.

I'm guessing that you added this property so that the entire background will display on the page when there is little page content. To get the effect you're looking for you may have to create a separate div, in a fixed position, and positioned center, with a z index smaller than your main #container.